# How to use a client-side component in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, next.js

I would like to use a D3 based React Component called `react-wordcloud`. It works great in React, but makes Nextjs crash with the following error:

> Server Error
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Based on several articles, I've tried wrote the following workarounds:

```js
// WORKAROUND 1
{typeof window === "undefined" ? 
     <div>loading...</div>) :  
     <WordCloud words={words} />
 }
 
 // WORKAROUND 2
{process.browser && <WordCloud words={words} />}

 // WORKAROUND 3
{process.browser && 
  <div suppressHydrationWarning>
  <WordCloud words={words} />
  </div>
}

 // WORKAROUND 4
<div suppressHydrationWarning>
<WordCloud words={words} />
</div>
```

None of them work. The build keeps crashing. Is there any solution to force NextJS to display a client-side component?

Answer (score 10):

In Next to render a component on the client-side only, you'll need to use `next/dynamic`. This will prevent the rendering of a component on the server, even if the page rendering the component is using SSR or SSG.

In the `WordCloud` component `dynamic` can be used like this:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const ReactWordCloud = dynamic(() => import('react-wordcloud'), {
  ssr: false,
})

export default function WordCloud({words}){
  return (
    <ReactWordCloud words={words}/>
  )
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: I tried this approach with a component using recoil, and it just threw an error, with no description of what the problem was :(